# Failed to send ok during RDP automation to legal notice banner

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

```
$server = “ServerName”
$Cred1 = New-Object -TypeName pscredential -ArgumentList “UserName”,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String ‘password’ -AsPlainText -Force);


Function Connect-Mstsc {


[cmdletbinding(SupportsShouldProcess,DefaultParametersetName=’UserPassword’)]
param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
ValueFromPipeline=$true,
ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
Position=0)]
[Alias(‘CN’)]
[string[]] $ComputerName,
[Parameter(ParameterSetName=’UserPassword’,Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
[Alias(‘U’)]
[string] $User,
[Parameter(ParameterSetName=’UserPassword’,Mandatory=$true,Position=2)]
[Alias(‘P’)]
[string] $Password,
[Parameter(ParameterSetName=’Credential’,Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
[Alias(‘C’)]
[PSCredential] $Credential,
[Alias(‘A’)]
[switch] $Admin,
[Alias(‘MM’)]
[switch] $MultiMon,
[Alias(‘F’)]
[switch] $FullScreen,
[Alias(‘Pu’)]
[switch] $Public,
[Alias(‘W’)]
[int] $Width,
[Alias(‘H’)]
[int] $Height,
[Alias(‘WT’)]
[switch] $Wait
)


begin {
[string]$MstscArguments = ”
switch ($true) {
{$Admin} {$MstscArguments += ‘/admin ‘}
{$MultiMon} {$MstscArguments += ‘/multimon ‘}
{$FullScreen} {$MstscArguments += ‘/f ‘}
{$Public} {$MstscArguments += ‘/public ‘}
{$Width} {$MstscArguments += “/w:$Width “}
{$Height} {$MstscArguments += “/h:$Height “}
}


if ($Credential) {
$User = $Credential.UserName
$Password = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
}
}
process {
foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
$ProcessInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$Process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process

# Remove the port number for CmdKey otherwise credentials are not entered correctly
if ($Computer.Contains(‘:’)) {
$ComputerCmdkey = ($Computer -split ‘:’)[0]
} else {
$ComputerCmdkey = $Computer
}


$ProcessInfo.FileName = “$($env:SystemRoot)\system32\cmdkey.exe”
$ProcessInfo.Arguments = “/generic:TERMSRV/$ComputerCmdkey /user:$User /pass:$($Password)”
$ProcessInfo.WindowStyle = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle]::Hidden
$Process.StartInfo = $ProcessInfo
if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($ComputerCmdkey,’Adding credentials to store’)) {
[void]$Process.Start()
}


$ProcessInfo.FileName = “$($env:SystemRoot)\system32\mstsc.exe”
$ProcessInfo.Arguments = “$MstscArguments /v $Computer”
$ProcessInfo.WindowStyle = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle]::Normal
$Process.StartInfo = $ProcessInfo
if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($Computer,’Connecting mstsc’)) {
[void]$Process.Start()
if ($Wait) {
$null = $Process.WaitForExit()
}
}
}
}
}


connect-mstsc -ComputerName $server -Credential $Cred1 -ErrorAction stop


##below code is used to skip certificate warning###


[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(‘System.Windows.Forms’)
# Get the ID of the process
$WindowsHandle = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.ProcessName -match ‘mstsc’ } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id
# Activate the window
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate($WindowsHandle) | Out-Null


[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait(“{TAB}”)
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait(“{TAB}”)
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait(“{TAB}”)
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait(“{ENTER}”)


##Below code needs to modified to click ok button legal notice banner


function Click-MouseButton
{
$signature=@’
[DllImport(“user32.dll”,CharSet=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);
‘@


$SendMouseClick = Add-Type -memberDefinition $signature -name “Win32MouseEventNew” -namespace Win32Functions -passThru


$SendMouseClick::mouse_event(0x00000002, 0, 0, 0, 0);
$SendMouseClick::mouse_event(0x00000004, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}


[system.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Remote Desktop Connection") | out-null


# Set the exactly position of cursor in some iexplore hyperlink between the (open parenthesis) below:
[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position
 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(790,675)
Click-MouseButton
```

Experts can someone help me to make the script works am using the above script to automate RDP connection and click ok button on legal notice screen during RDP login but script failed to send OK button,Any help much appreciated!

if above script is not able to make it then suggest some ways to automate RDP connection to the server and bypass legal notice banner

Comment: What do mean by "legal notice banner"? A certificate warning?

Comment: Nope the screen which shows am an authorized user message to enter into the system

Comment: Are you an admin of that infrastructure?